# Запятые в предложении "Машины загородили дорогу(,) и нельзя было проехать ни взад(,) ни вперед"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, егэ, сложное-предложение

> Машины загородили дорогу(?) и нельзя было проехать ни взад(?) ни вперед.

Где должны стоять запятые? Объясните постановку.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Comment: Если это ЕГЭ (см. метки), то должен быть единственный убедительный ответ. А тут спорная ситуция с НИ...НИ. Странно, что такое включают в ЕГЭ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не ставится запятая в цельных фразеологизированных сочетаниях с повторяющимися союзами **и… и, ни… ни** (они соединяют слова с противопоставляемыми значениями):

и день и ночь, и стар и млад, и смех и горе, и там и сям, и то и се, и туда и сюда, ни два ни полтора, ни дать ни взять, ни сват ни брат, ни взад ни вперед, ни дна ни покрышки, ни то ни се, ни стать ни сесть, ни жив ни мертв, ни да ни нет, ни слуху ни духу, ни себе ни людям, ни рыба ни мясо, ни так ни сяк, ни пава ни ворона, ни шатко ни валко, ни тот ни этот и др.

То же при парных сочетаниях слов, когда третьего не дано: и муж и жена, и земля и небо .

[источник](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/)

Корректно: **Машины загородили дорогу, и нельзя было проехать ни взад ни вперед.**

Никуда — ни взад ни вперед.
Нельзя было проехать ни взад, ни вперед, но можно влево и вправо.

Comment: Дорога  (если это не перекресток) имеет два направления, а не четыре. И надо учитывать, что запятая соответствует перечислительной интонации, обычно такая интонация и применяется.

Comment: @Jasmin Вот вам примеры из корпуса, в которых _слово_ ни взад ни вперед имеет значение невозможно двинуться.

Так это самое дело и затянулось: ни взад ни вперед. 

Она застряла в тесной толпе и, не двигаясь ни взад ни вперед, походила на птичку, которую сильно стиснули в кулаке.

В базарный день проезду нет, а пуще обозы; иной раз всю улицу запрудят — ни взад ни вперед!  

[Вот](https://phraseology.academic.ru/1099/%D0%9D%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4_%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%91%D0%B4) ссылка на толкование.

Comment: Нет сомнений, что обе формы существуют, но есть вопрос, как их выбрать.  Я использую два показателя: семантический и  интонационный. Семантический принцип : наличие или отсутствие обобщенного значения "никуда", интонационный: нет паузы, произношение в одну фразу или наличие перечислительной интонации и паузы. В приведенных Вами примерах один относится к деепричастному обороту (там паузы нет), а во втором  много знаков препинания (их надо выразить в устной речи), оборот стоит в конце,  его удобнее произнести в одну фразу. Поэтому структура очень важна, а в каждом предложении своя структура.

Answer (score 2):

**Машины загородили дорогу, и нельзя было проехать ни взад, ни вперед.**

Существует фразеологическое выражение ***ни взад ни вперед***, но оно употребляется реже, чем обычный вариант с запятой.

Примеры:

1) Одним словом, попала змея, что **ни туда и ни сюда, ни взад ни вперед**! [Михаил Бубеннов. Белая береза / части 3-6 (1942-1952)]

2) Надоело топтаться на одном месте – **ни взад, ни вперед**. [В. П. Катаев. Юношеский роман (1980-1981)]

**Ни взад, ни вперед** не продвинуться… Боевики с трех сторон открыли шквальный огонь из всех видов стрелкового вооружения. [В. Евдомашкин. Побеждать ― наука непростая (2003) ]

... **ни взад, ни вперед** ничего не подавалось и не пробивалось, прожигало грудь комком пламени, губы понапрасну схватывали воздух. [Виктор Астафьев. Последний поклон (1968-1991)]

Даже жалко было смотреть, в какое положение они себя посадили: **ни взад, ни вперед.** [Д. А. Фурманов. Мятеж (1924)]

Comment: Поддерживаю ответ, хотя просили объяснить обе запятые :)

Comment: Первая запятая настолько очевидна, что всем лень ее объяснять :)